# Encrypt data and sign on Android using NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, cryptography, public

I have some data that needs must be encrypted and signed using public key provided by the server and then sent to different server. Encryption and signing should be done in C++ library. TLS/SSL will be used, but it is not enough - edge server receiving this message must not be able to read aforementioned data, only data required for routing this message inside our infrastructure to proper server.
From what I gather I shouldn't use libssl.so ([as written here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider?utm_campaign=android_discussion_ndkchanges_062716&utm_source=anddev&utm_medium=blog)), yet I don't want to use non-native TLS - I need only public key and symmetric cryptography.
Right now it seems that I could use Crypto++ or Botan or any other capable library, but maybe there is something native that I could use?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used [mbedtls](https://tls.mbed.org/), which is very easy to use and has pretty good, thought far from perfect, documentation. Examples are relatively scarce but are enough.